# Pass state from child component to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 jsx files,

How I can get **this.props.result** in **Parent.jsx** from **Child.jsx** ?

**File Child.jsx:**

```
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result: 'logout'
        };
        this.login_action = this.login_action.bind(this);
        this.logout_action = this.logout_action.bind(this);
    }

    login_action(){
        this.setState({result: 'login'})
    }

    logout_action(){
        this.setState({result: 'logout'})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.status}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
                <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

export default Child;

**File Parent.jsx:**

```
 class Parent extends React.Component {
     render () {
        if(this.props.result.localeCompare("login") > -1){
            return(<Child  status="logout" />)
        }else{
            return(<Child  status="logout"/>)
        }
     }
 }
 render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: There are some issues in your code. In Child.jsx, button click handler should be `{this.login_action}` and `{this.logout_action}` and In Parent.jsx you are returning same thing in if-else

Comment: Code part formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says,

> In React, sharing state is accomplished by moving it up to the closest common ancestor of the components that need it. This is called "lifting state up". (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

You should move the "result" state to the Parent component. See this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/nusFqnNRHlKG2UgXnjgo/) for the example of lifting state up from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass callback function from Parent to Child. Like this:

Parent.jsx

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  render () {

    if(this.props.result.localeCompare("login") > -1){
        return(<Child onResultChange={(res) => this.onResultChange(res)} status="logout" />)

    }else{
        return(<Child onResultChange={(res) => this.onResultChange(res)} status="logout"/>)

    }
  }

  onResultChange(newResult) {
    //do what you need with new result value here
  }
 }
 render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Child.jsx

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        result: 'logout'
    };
    this.login_action = this.login_action.bind(this);
    this.logout_action = this.logout_action.bind(this);

    }

    login_action(){
        this.setState({result: 'login'});
        this.props.onResultChange('login');
    }

    logout_action(){
        this.setState({result: 'logout'});
        this.props.onResultChange('logout');
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.status}</h1>
            <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
            <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```